# install tflearn but not found contrib

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

With Ubuntu 18.04 64bit , anaconda3 , and python3

```
>>> import tflearn
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/a1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>       from . import config
>     File "/home/a1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 5, in 
>       from .variables import variable
>     File "/home/a1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

But I can't install it.

```
pip install tflearn
```

> Requirement already satisfied: tflearn in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.2)
>   Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tflearn) (5.3.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tflearn) (1.12.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tflearn) (1.15.4)

Pleeeeease help me :<

Comment: "With Ubuntu 18.10 64bit , anaconda3 , and python3" Are you sure you installed tflearn into the right environment?

Comment: Oh maybe I'm in Ubuntu 18.04 :O

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the error message, it seems you do not have `tensorflow` installed. Install it using

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and then check.